# What's the best way to upgrade from a Drake version that is >3 months old?

Tags: upgrade, drake

I have some code using an older version of Drake, and I'd like to upgrade to a much newer version.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

For the quickest but most informative way to upgrade, you should incrementally upgrade across releases that are 3 months or less apart: 
https://drake.mit.edu/release_notes/release_notes.html

### More words

For stable public API that needs to be removed, we try to mark old API as [deprecated for about a 3-month period](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/drake__deprecated_8h.html); these deprecations should include warnings that direct you towards newer API (or alternatives). In C++, this should show up as a build or runtime warning. In Python code, it should show up as a runtime warning. In Bazel code, it should show up during build process.

At present (2021-04), Drake releases on a monthly cadence, so generally you just need to skip 3 minor versions.